# How can i see the result form my typeScript in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, typescript

**This is my HTML**
*i changed all the code

```
<div class="testCenter">
    <h1>{{teston()}}</h1>
</div>
```

**This is my .ts code** the function teston() i dont know if it make sense

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Carte } from '../mesClass/Carte'; // importation de la class Carte

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gestion-poker',
  templateUrl: './gestion-poker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestion-poker.component.css']
})
export class GestionPokerComponent implements OnInit {

  test:Carte;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  teston(){

  return this.test.carte(1);
    
  }

}
```

This is my class Carte.ts

```
export class Carte {

    // Attributs
    sorte = new Array;
    
    carte(sor){

        this.sorte = sor;
      

        sor = ["hello","Bob"];
       
        
    }

}
```

**So what i want to do is to see in my HTML:
*Bob*


nothing seems to work am i missing something?**

Comment: Yes, you need to set a property in your TS, and then you need to reference that _bound_ property in your HTML with curly braces. It's described here in the Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#show-the-hero

Comment: By `return this.cartes(sor, val);` you just build an endless loop. And `return this.carte.cartes(1, 3);` wont work, since `sor` and `val` should be arrays, but you use numbers as inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think:

1. Your test is not defined. You need to create a new Carte type object.
2. In your carte class you are creating a public globa variable that's type is an Array, but in the function cart(sor), you overwrite it with a number.

Depending on your code, i think you want somethink like this:

```
export class Carte {
    sorte: Array<string> = ['hello', 'Bob'];
    
    carte(sor){
      return this.sorte[sor]  
    }
}
```

And in your ts file something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Carte } from '../mesClass/Carte'; // importation de la class Carte

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gestion-poker',
  templateUrl: './gestion-poker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gestion-poker.component.css']
})
export class GestionPokerComponent implements OnInit {

  test:Carte;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.test = new Carte();
  }


  teston(){
     return this.test.carte(1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice, and thanks for not just posting the code, the explanations make it so much easier.